# Making a function to get percentage of multiple rows in dataframe R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, percentage

I have a dataframe of hundreds of samples and thousands of variables. But here I give a simple data frame (my_data) as an illustration. I want to get the percentage of the variable relative to the sum of gene_count based on which cluster the gene belong (the gene can be in multiple clusters). I know how to get the percentage of each using dataframe operation. However, since I am new to coding, I am trying to make a function to get the percentage. Could anyone helps how to get percentage for each gene using my function (percent)? The result would be the percentage on the column "percent". Thank you very much.

```
gene = c("CD63", "PTN", "MT2A", "PTGDS", "DBI", "TIMP1", "COX6C", "APLP2", "PTN", "GPC1")
gene_count = c(10, 15, 5, 15, 10, 25, 5, 5, 5, 5)
cluster = c(1,2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 4 )
percent = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.5, 0.15, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
my_data = data.frame(gene, gene_count, cluster, percent)
my_data


percent = function(gene, cluster){
for (gene in c(data$gene)){
if (data$gene == gene & data$cluster == cluster)
print(data$gene_count[which(data$gene == gene & data$cluster == cluster)]/sum(data$gene_count))
else print("Gene is not expressed in this cluster")
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `prop.table(my_data$gene_count)` Or `my_data$gene_count/sum(my_data$gene_count)`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I got this idea, but I want to learn about using function to find the specific gene.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the function in the following way :

```
percent <- function(data, my_gene, my_cluster) {
  sub_data <- subset(data, gene == my_gene & cluster == my_cluster)
  if(nrow(sub_data)) sum(sub_data$gene_count)/sum(data$gene_count)
  else cat("Gene is not expressed in this cluster")
}

percent(my_data, 'PTN', 2)
#[1] 0.15

percent(my_data, 'ABC', 2)
#Gene is not expressed in this cluster
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well. I still do not get the meaning of  "if(nrow(sub_data)) sum(sub_data$gene_count)/sum(data$gene_count)". I understand for if statement that if the condition  "nrow(sub_data)" is true then it will operate the command "sum(sub_data$gene_count)/sum(data$gene_count)". But how the nrow(sub_data) which return to a number (right?) make it true and make the following command to work?

Comment: In R, 0 is treated as `FALSE` and any other number is treated as `TRUE` so we use that fact here. This is same as doing `if(nrow(sub_data) > 0)` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful.

### percent_in_total

```
percent_in_total = function(data, gene_in, cluster_in){
  data %>% 
  filter(gene == gene_in & cluster == cluster_in) %>% 
  .[["gene_count"]]/sum(gene_count)
}
percent_in_total(my_data,"PTN",2)
[1] 0.15

# data.table version
library(data.table)
percent_in_total = function(data, gene_in, cluster_in){
  setDT(data)[,
              .SD[gene == gene_in & cluster == cluster_in, gene_count]] / sum(gene_count)
}
percent_in_total(my_data,"PTN",2)
[1] 0.15
```

### percent_in_cluster

I prefer to use `data.table`'s grammer. To explain the process, for the gene `MT2A`, `.SD[gene == gene_in & cluster == cluster_in, gene_count]` is the number `gene_count = 5` and `sum(.SD[cluster==cluster_in,gene_count])]` is the total gene number of `cluster = 3`, which is `5+5`.

```
library(data.table)
percent_in_cluster = function(data, gene_in, cluster_in){
  setDT(data)[,
              .SD[gene==gene_in & cluster==cluster_in, gene_count] / sum(.SD[cluster==cluster_in,gene_count])]
}
percent_in_cluster(my_data,"MT2A",3)
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helps. I am still confused with this operation .[[]], could you explain? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, in `.[[]]`, the dot means  the previous input dataframe. `[["gene_count"]]` extract the column. All that act like `dt[["gene_count"]]`. If thsi is useful, you can accept this anser, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. But there is one issue actually. Is there any way to know the percentage of the gene in its cluster? I was looking for two percentage of each gene relative to total gene count in all cluster and relative to total gene count for each cluster. For example gene "MT2A" which is expressed in cluster 3, to know its percentage in cluster 3? It should result (5/(5+5)=0.5, there only two genes in cluster 3: MT2A and COX6C)

Comment: @MK Huda The function I give is to calculate the percentage in total gene_count. You also want to calculate the percentage in its cluster. Ok, I get it. I will updated it  in my answer.

Comment: I tried to apply this function with my big dataframe, but it turns out that the result showing the percentage of the gene in each cluster where it is expressed instead of in its cluster where we specify the cluster in the function meaning the output are multiples instead of single percentage. Although I got the idea and I thought it was correct, but somehow it is not. Unfortunately I still cannot figure out why.

Comment: I have updated the function `percent_in_cluster`, now it should be fine. The edited part is `.SD[gene==gene_in & cluster==cluster_in, gene_count]`.